# AWS RDS Serverless Data Types

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-serverless

I've asked this in the AWS RDS forum but received no response. I thought I'd try here.

AWS RDS serverless returns metadata for columns in a query response. The metadata inlcudes an integer Type and a string TypeName for each column. Is there a list of all possible values for Type and TypeName such that MySql datatypes can be mapped to them? I have not found such a list in the RDS or MySql documentation.

Thanks